# Unable To Access Public Images Possible Routing Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, paperclip, show

I'm working on a project and trying to render some images sitting under the public directory in one of my show views. I'm able to access these images just fine on my index view, but it's not quite so easy for show views it would seem.

So lets say in my view I have something like the following:

```
<%= "<img src=\"images/16x16/actions/filesave.png\" class=\"icon" title=\"save\">"%>
```

This would work in my index view perfectly fine, but for some strange reason I get this routing error in my show view:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/uploads/images/16x16/actions/filesave.png"):

I noticed that for some peculiar reason it's injecting the "/uploads/" route right before the "/images..." this is the cause of my problem and I can't figure out why or how to stop it. This only happens with my show views.

Now there's a lot going on in my routes.rb file, I know it's ugly but I do plan on going in there and cleaning it up when I get the chance.

```
resources :upload_images

  get "upload_image/new"

  get "upload_image/index"

  get "upload_image/show"

  get "upload_image/delete"

  resources :help_categories

  resources :global_configs

  resources :competitions

  match '/teams/register', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'register'
  match '/teams/invite_users', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'invite_users'
  match '/teams/view_invitations', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'view_invitations'
  match '/teams/ignore', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'ignore'
  match '/teams/leave_team', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'leave_team'
  resources :teams



  resources :competitions do
    resources :matches
  end

  resources :registers
  resources :players do
    collection do
      post :edit_individual
      put :update_individual
      get :results
    end
  end
  resources :tournaments

  resources :matches

  resources :upload_categories

  resources :uploads, :except => [:new]

  match '/download/:id' => 'uploads#download'

  devise_for :users do    
    match 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  resources :users, :except => [:new] do
    member do
      get 'upload_files'
      get 'delete_files'
    end
  end

  resources :games

  devise_for :videolinks


  resources :topics do
    collection do
      get "mark_all_viewed"
    end
    member do
      get 'show_new'
    end
  end


   resources :posts do
    member do
      get 'quote'
      get 'topic'
    end
  end

  resources :forums do
    member do
      get 'confirm_delete'
    end
  end

  resources :blog_entries, :except => [:index]
  resources :categories
  resources :videolinks
  resources :competition_games
  resources :competitions
  resources :news  
  resources :events 

  match 'uploads/find_uploads' => 'uploads#find_uploads'
  match 'uploads/add_upload_image' => 'uploads#add_upload_image'
  match 'forum_root' => 'forums#index'
  match 'upload_root' => 'uploads#index'
  match 'user' => 'forums#index'
  match 'news_root' => 'news#index'
  match 'topic_post' => 'forums#index'
  match 'quote_post' => 'forums#index'
  match 'new_upload' => 'forums#index'
  match 'videolinks/:id', :to => 'videolinks#show'
  match 'register' => 'users#sign_up'
  match 'login' => 'users#sign_in'

  match 'users/find_users' => 'users#find_users'
  match '/users/get_states/:country' => 'users#states'
  match '/ban/:username' => 'users#ban'
  match '/ban_user/:username' => 'users#ban_user'
  match ':username' => 'users#show'
  match ':username/edit' => 'users#edit'
  match ':username/delete_files_all' => 'uploads#index'
  match ':username/delete_files' => 'users#delete_files'
  match ':username/upload_files' => 'users#upload_files'
  match ':username/password/edit' => 'users#editpass'
  match ':username/edit_file/:id' => 'uploads#edit'
  match '/maketakeadmin/:username' => 'users#maketakeadmin'
  match ':username/destroy' => 'users#destroy'

  root :to => "home#index"

  resources :categories do
    member do
      get 'confirm_delete'
    end
  end
```

Another developer worked on the upload section of this application and it uses paperclip. By default it saves uploads in the public directory and we didn't want that so he told me he did some weird hotfix to save uploads to a private directory off of the root of the application called "uploads". Not sure if this might have anything to do with it.

Comment: Awesome I just got my Tumbleweed badge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a forward slash at the start of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this:

```
<%= image_tag "/images/16x16/actions/filesave.png", class: "icon", alt: "save" %>
```